# Combobox Itemsource throws Exception when setting to a single item collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, powershell, combobox

When setting the `ItemSource` of a **WPF Combobox** to a `DataRowCollection` programmatically from Powershell with just one entry, I'm getting this error message:

> Ausnahme beim Festlegen von "ItemsSource": "Der Wert
>   "System.Data.DataRow" vom Typ "System.Data.DataRow" kann nicht in den
>   Typ "System.Collections.IEnumerable" konvertiert werden.

which roughly translates to:

> Exception on setting of "ItemsSource": The value "System.Data.DataRow"
>   of type "System.Data.DataRow" cannot be converted to type
>   "System.Collections.IEnumerable

If my query results in a `DataRowCollection` with two or more entries, the setter `ItemSource` of the `ComboBox` just works fine. The function is written in Powershell and I already tried to cast the `DataRowCollection` to an array to make a workaround for this exception.

What should I deliver to the `ItemSource` setter, if the `DataRowCollection` has just one entry?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

**Edit**
Here is some code as requested:

```
$connection = new-object system.data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($connectionString)
$command = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand($sqlCommand,$connection)
$connection.Open()

$adapter = New-Object System.Data.sqlclient.sqlDataAdapter $command
$dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$adapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null

$connection.Close()

$rows = $dataSet.Tables[0].Rows #i am querying only one table
#$combobox is the combobox element of the wpf window
$combobox.ItemSource = $rows #If $rows has just one element, this is the point where the exception occurs
```

Comment: it says u are trying to set a DataRow where it expects an ienumerable, show us some code.. it needs to be a collection even if it is one item that one item has to be in collection.

Answer (score 0):

I found a little workaround.
Now i am casting the single `DataRow` item to an array and adding an empty string. Without adding an empty string, the same exception occurs.

```
$rows = $dataSet.Tables[0].Rows
#simple hack, to ensure this method always returns an array. 
#if just one element is in Rows, wpf complains about a single datarow not being an enumerable
if($rows.Count -eq 1) 
{ 
    $rows = @($rows,"")
}
```

Now the setter `ItemSource` accepts the `$rows`, but of course, the empty string will be shown in the `ComboBox`.